# Tcp connection pool is not working after 1 minute

Tags: spring, sockets, soap, spring-integration

I have SOAP service, which used tcp connections for interaction with external service.
  I'm use connection pool for this tcp service. When I start my app and send first SOAP request - all works fine, but if I'm wait 1 min - then I don't get the response. But when I sniff traffic with Wireshark - I see, what response is returned. 
  And small additional - if I'm no wait 1 minute and send new requests - all works fine. Problem occurs only if the wait 1 minute. This my configuration for pool and tcp:

```
<beans profile="single">
    <bean id="testConnectionFactory" class="com.test.provider.impl.ProviderTcpConnectionFactory">
        <constructor-arg name="host" value="localhost"/>
        <constructor-arg name="port" value="7700"/>
        <property name="connectionTimeout" value="10000"/>
        <property name="soTimeout" value="60000"/>
        <property name="deserializer" ref="testDeserializer"/>
        <property name="singleUse" value="true"/>
    </bean>
</beans>

<beans profile="pool">
    <bean id="testConnection" class="com.test.provider.impl.ProviderTcpConnectionFactory">
        <constructor-arg name="host" value="localhost"/>
        <constructor-arg name="port" value="7700"/>
        <property name="connectionTimeout" value="10000"/>
        <property name="soTimeout" value="60000"/>
        <property name="deserializer" ref="testDeserializer"/>
        <property name="singleUse" value="true"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="testConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.CachingClientConnectionFactory">
        <constructor-arg ref="testConnection"/>
        <constructor-arg value="5"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

In logs I see next line

```
DEBUG [org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNetConnection] Closed single use socket after timeout
```

As I understand - socket closed after soTimeout is expired. But how to use pool without closing connections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the `CachingClientConnectioNFactory`; it doesn't properly handle connections that time out in this way; the connection is not actually closed and the reader thread is terminated.

Please open a [JIRA Issue](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/INT); thanks.

A work around might be to remove the soTimeout attribute; you could also put an soTimeout on the server side so it initiates the close.

Actually, given that you are using `single-use="true"` (a new socket for each connection), you will get no benefit from using the `CachingClientConnectionFactory`; it's intended to provide a pool of shared connections.

Comment: Thank you. I' remove "soTimeout" attribute, but my I also doesn't have a response after 1 minute. Thank you. I'm removed "soTimeout" attribute, but I also doesn't have a response after 1 minute. As I understand - this problem is resolved only after this bug is fixed?

Comment: Yes, it needs a fix; however, as I said, if you are using a new socket for each connection (`single-use="true"`) then you really don't need the `CachingClientConnectionFactory`; it is only useful when using a pool of shared connections. Also, you can set a `remote-timeout` on the gateway rather than relying on the socket timeout. In that case, the gateway will timeout, throw an exception and close the socket, which is more desirable.

Comment: You can also set `using-nio="true"` the implementation is different and the problem won't occur in that case. But it's still better to use the `remote-timeout` to detect a lack of response.

Comment: Hello, Gary.
Thank you for quickly response. For now I'm removed "soTimeout" from my factory, set "singleUse" to false and replaced "reply-timeout" by "remote-timeout" on my tcp gateway. For now all responses backed normally. I'm right, what my configuration is correct for using connection pool? And what is a main difference between soTimeout, reply-timeout and remote-timeout?

Comment: `remote-timeout` is the time the gateway waits to get the reply; if it fires, the connection is closed and an exception is thrown (however, you need to update to 2.2.5 for this to work properly with a caching connection factory). The soTimeout is on the socket itself but that doesn't work properly at the moment with a caching connection factory. `send-timeout` is a timeout used when sending the reply to the reply channel - it is used rarely - it only applies  when the channel might block (such as a queue channel that is full). Your configuration as stated sounds good.

Comment: Hello.
 Thank you for response. I'm updated Spring Integration to version 2.2.5 and all is ok. But I find another problem. After stopping my application - all connections, which Connection Factory is created not closed.